# Returning 5 results SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

This is kinda hard to explain for me. But I'll tell you what my goal is step by step. I have a table that is similar down below. My goal is to return 5 results (LIMIT 5) on every 5 rows by specifying only the names, and I want the results to be in order as is.

```
id  | names
1     Michael 
2.    Albert
3.    William       
4.    Abraham  
5.    Leonardo  
6.    Elvis  
7.    Mozart 
8.    Martin  
9.    Benjamin  
10.   George 
11.   Napoleon
12.   John
13.   Christopher 
14.   Michelangelo
15.   Thomas 
16.   Gandhi
17.   Cleopatra
18.   Neil 
19.   Marilyn 
20.   Bill
```

Let's say I want to return 5 results WHERE the names **Mozart** is visible in rows.

Here is my desired results: (The name **Mozart** is visible right after the next 5 rows)

```
    6.    Elvis  
    7.    Mozart 
    8.    Martin  
    9.    Benjamin  
    10.   George
```

Or Let's say I want to return 5 results WHERE the names **Michelangelo** is visible in rows.

Here is my desired results: (The name **Michelangelo** is visible right after the next `two` 5 rows)

```
     11.   Napoleon
     12.   John
     13.   Christopher 
     14.   Michelangelo
     15.   Thomas
```

Or Let's say I want to return 5 results WHERE the names **Christopher** is visible in rows.

Here is my desired results, same thing as the 2nd example: (The name **Christopher** is visible right after the next `two` 5 rows)

```
     11.   Napoleon
     12.   John
     13.   Christopher 
     14.   Michelangelo
     15.   Thomas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with some arithmetic on the `id`:

```
select st.*
from similartable st cross join
     (select id from similartable where name = 'Mozart') st1
where floor((st.id - 1)/5) = floor((st1.id - 1)/5)
limit 5;
```

EDIT:

If the `id`s are not in order, then the problem is a bit more challenging.  I would do it with variables.  Here is one way:

```
select st.*
from (select st.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from similartable st cross join
          (select @rn := -1) vars
      order by id
     ) st join
     (select st.*, (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1) as rn
      from similartable st cross join
           (select @rn1 := -1) vars
      order by id
     ) st1
     on st1.name = 'Mozart'
where floor(st.rn / 5) = floor(st1.rn / 5)
limit 5;
```

Comment: This is gonna work like a charm, but the problem is sometimes, I delete rows and ids ended up not in order. There will be some missing rows.

Comment: And for some reasons, it is only returning 4 rows in total.

Comment: But let's say 8.Martin is deleted. And I want to return 5 results WHERE the names Elvis is visible in rows. It will only return 4 rows which is 6. Elvis  
7.    Mozart  
9.    Benjamin 10.   George

Comment: It is still returning ONLY 4 rows

Comment: My bad, yes it is working now! I didn't your edited answer! Thanks a lot!